# What is the silver checkered circle on the iPhone 14 camera panel?

Tags: hardware, camera

Here's the image for reference:

[image: iphone 14 camera panel grey dot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It's a microphone

After a little research, I was able to find this filed on the [US Patent Office site.](https://image-ppubs.uspto.gov/dirsearch-public/print/downloadPdf/20200221002)

[image: iPhone Back Diagram]

The item in question is #386.  Per the patent filing in the PDF, it refers to that component as a "microphone."  As this is a patent filing, the final RTM (release to manufacturing) product varies slightly with the LED strobe (flash) and camera(s) position varying.